# Issue with tic tac toe interface

Tags: html, css

I'm making a tic tac toe game for a school proyect, I've already the interface but when I insert a text all the row move down.

[Interface picture...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGQ9o.png)

[Text inserted...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8p1G.png)

This is my html code...

```
<div id="game-space">
    <label class="casilla"></label>
    <label class="casilla">X</label>
    <label class="casilla"></label>
    <br>
    <label class="casilla"></label>
    <label class="casilla"></label>
    <label class="casilla"></label>
    <br>
    <label class="casilla"></label>
    <label class="casilla"></label>
    <label class="casilla">O</label>
</div>
    <br>
    <button id="new-game">Juego Nuevo</button>
```

This is my css code...

```
#game-space{

    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 310px;
    height: 310px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    border-radius: 15px;
}
.casilla{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: solid 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

I've used div, p, and button tag too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve  expected result, please use below CSS and remove br tags in the html
1.Removed br tags
2.Increased width and height of game space div
3.Used overflow:hidden for the casilla div, as the div content never exceed to display scroll(as values are X O only)

```
#game-space{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 370px;
    height: 370px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    border-radius: 15px;
}
.casilla{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: solid 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/OXxVvA

Comment: @Danny908, check the updated codepen url  http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/OXxVvA..Hope this works for you :)

Comment: @Naga Sai A, thanks for you answer, now is working perfect :D

Comment: thanks @Danny908 , Could you please mark my post as answered :)